# Get branches from bitbucket repository

Tags: branch, bitbucket

I have used "gentlero/bitbucket-api" in php to get bitbucket information.
    https://github.com/gentlero/bitbucket-api

I want to get branches from bitbucket repository But unable to get branches information.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can get branch via followed code. try this code. hopefully help

```
    $result=Bitbucket::connection('alternative')->api('Repositories\Repository')->branches('repo name', 'api name');
    $data=json_decode($result->getContent());
    dd($data);
```